# Regex - including the colon

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I would like to use the Regex to match the first twelve characters of a string I've received. I'm receiving the string and I want to validate which string to discard and which to keep. Once I've validated the string I then instantiate an object based on the information in the string.

In my example I want to check for a specific character (A), eight numbers, a colon and then either B|C followed by an D. This pattern identifies a string which I would like to work with. However the following pattern fails to match and I suspect it is due to the colon

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(my_string,"A[0-9]{8,}:(B|C)D"))
```

I want this to match, where the zeroes are any number 0-9 and where the B is interchangeable with a C. I need to verify that the colon is present, as there are cases where the string may be malformed.

Example of characters that should pass the Regex pattern;

```
A00000000:BD
```

Comment: What do you mean by `if fails`? How exactly it fails?

Comment: You have `A|B followed by C` in the text and then later `B|C followed by D`. Which is it?

Comment: Not sure why you have the comma in `{8,}` rather than just `{8}`, but your regex seems to match the string you gave.

Comment: Passing it the string and it fails, other research indicates that I'd have to use a \ to compare the colon but this just escapes the string

Comment: When you say "verify the colon is present" does that mean you will want to match <code>A00000000BD</code> as well and perhaps add the <code>:</code> in?

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://ideone.com/giNLkl

Comment: Along with checking the normal characters I also want to identify the presence of the colon.

Answer (score 3):

That regex should work. A few suggestions:

- `{8,}` matches 8 and more characters.
- The entire regex will also match substrings of a longer string (i.e. `"XYZA12345678:CDEFG"`). If you don't want that, anchor your regex.
- `(B|C)` can be replaced by `[BC]`

So try this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(my_string,"^A[0-9]{8}:[BC]D"))
```

Comment: You could change [0-9] to \d too if you wanted

Comment: @spots: No. `\d` also matches non-ASCII numerals. He doesn't seem to want that.

Comment: While this is solid in theory i'm failing to match with this case, this part i'm checking for is at the front of a longer string and I want to stop validating at the D. I'm using this regex to check a portion of my string before pulling it to pieces. This check is to filter out strings which aren't required.

Comment: @SimonJohnson: That's exactly what this regex is doing, and what the `IsMatch()` method is there for. There must be some other problem. Please edit your question and post a code sample that allows us to reproduce the problem.